# Matching over related tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with names, `nametable`:

```
id | name
---------
1  | alice
2  | bob
3  | charlie
```

A second with related data, `datatable`:

```
id | data
------------
1  | chicken
2  | fish
2  | chicken
3  | spaghetti
```

Now I want to find matching matching data between two names of `nametable`:

```
name1 | name2 | data
--------------------
alice | bob   | chicken
```

Now I have this:

```
SELECT nt0.name, nt1.name, nt0.data
FROM nametable AS nt0
INNER JOIN datatable AS dt0
ON nt0.id = dt0.id
LEFT JOIN nametable AS nt1
INNER JOIN datatable AS dt1
ON nt1.id = dt1.id
WHERE dt0.data = dt1.data AND nt0.name < nt1.name;
```

But it doesn't work. I guess the `JOIN`s are the reason, but I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: Odd syntax, there's a missing ON clause.

Comment: No only that, why the hell does bob connected to alice?

Comment: I know, I guess that's the problem I want to match a with b; c with d; and then (a b) with (c d)

Comment: What? Still doesn't sound logical

Answer (score 1):

You can do a self join on derived tables:

```
SELECT
    t1.name, t2.name, t1.data
FROM (
    SELECT n.id, n.name, d.data
    FROM nametable n
    INNER JOIN datatable d
        ON d.id = n.id
) t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT n.id, n.name, d.data
    FROM nametable n
    INNER JOIN datatable d
        ON d.id = n.id
)t2
    ON t2.data = t1.data
    AND t2.id > t1.id
```